# Custom 'actionBarTabStyle' does not override AppCombat Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-appcompat

I'm trying now for hours to override the AppCombat Theme for a custom Tab Style, but my changes doesn't have any effect. Here is my style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs.AppTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabs.AppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">

    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

I use android-support-libray-v7 for using `ActionBarTabStyle` in older Android versions. This is the tab_bar_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />
```

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/boni_red" />
```

In the `TabActivity` class, I just add some tabs using `TabHost` and the layout for this activity looks like this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TabBarLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/header_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/boni_red"
        android:text="@string/app_name_capital"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">
    </TabWidget>


</LinearLayout>
```

I just followed the tutorial provided by [android developer page](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/4.4/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).
The tabbar in my application looks like the light one in the picture.
[image: TabBar]

Any suggestions why my style does not override the standard style? Actually everything should be in red color! Do I make anything wrong?
Thanks and best regards,
Max

Comment: Have you checked that all you values version override in the same way?  Look at you styles in values-v11 & values-v14 too.

Comment: It's the same, I just added `android:` `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs.AppTheme</item>` , but I don't use values-v14, is this a problem?

Comment: Hmm ok. No that's not a problem. And I guess your manifest has been updated to use your custom theme? (Sorry, I know it sounds obvious but it's hard to know)

Comment: Yes, in the application tag I added `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`, otherwise the `AppCombat` theme also wouldn't be adopted.

Comment: Try using "android:background" instead of just "background". My styles all use android:XXX apart from the value-v14 one.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, I already tried it.

Comment: Try adding <style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="AppTheme"> </style> and then applying AppCompatTheme in your Manifest file. Remember to do the same in the other style for the regular android one as well (if at all you have created another file).

Comment: Use this for styling your action bar, it gives the code as well. http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0):

add following to:values-v11 (Do not ignore ‘android:’)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs.AppTheme</item>
```

modify following in styles.xml (Do not ignore ‘android:’)

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
```

`